# Count highest value in data frame in R

Tags: r, count, max

I have the below data frame (DF). I need to count how many times/years for each station has recorded maximum avg. temp, minumum avg. temp and maximum total precipitation.

In each row of DF above, year is followed by max avg. temp, min avg. temp and total avg. precipitation. For example, if in year 1985 highest max avg. temperature is recorded in station 1, it should count as one and so on.

Any suggestion or help is appreciated.

Thanks.

```
DF:



     St_name         Met_data
    station1       1985 15.33 4.33 780.1, 1986 12.7 2.18 505.3, 1987 17.76 6.33 793.6, 1988 17.35 4.53 541, 1989 15.65 3.98 793.7, 1990 16.9 5.96 1169.4, 1991 16.42 5.26 790.6, 1992 14.99 5.04 932.6, 1993 13.96 4.75 1420.7, 1994 14.96 3.79 668.8, 1995 15 3.67 952.9, 1996 13.77 2.4 808.5, 1997 14.69 3.26 773.5, 1998 17.22 6.25 1126.4, 1999 16.35 4.32 921.9, 2000 14.55 2.83 893.9, 2001 15.71 4.33 1118.8, 2002 15.61 3.96 1000.4, 2003 14.83 2.84 911.7, 2004 14.9 4 965.1, 2005 16.16 4.7 647.7, 2006 16.18 5.14 800.8, 2007 15.52 4.15 890.3, 2008 14.35 2.91 1271.9, 2009 14.4 3.77 1343.8, 2010 15.32 4.57 1145.4, 2011 15.41 4.54 857.3, 2012 17.39 5.4 745, 2013 15.26 3.51 811.4, 2014 13.8 2.37 986.3
    station2       1985 19.27 7.81 1465.5, 1986 20.37 8.81 1201.3, 1987 20.95 8.72 949.2, 1988 20.03 7.53 1104.6, 1989 19.11 7.42 1050.1, 1990 20.53 8.76 1486.2, 1991 20.21 9.53 1164.4, 1992 19.55 8.51 913.6, 1993 18.7 8.24 1485.1, 1994 19.43 8.42 1171.7, 1995 19.62 7.41 1084.9, 1996 19.01 6.29 1212.4, 1997 18.85 6.76 1243.2, 1998 21 8.27 1261.1, 1999 21.28 7.99 1122.4, 2000 19.99 7.74 1242.7, 2001 20.13 7.59 1305.8, 2002 20.13 7.69 1563, 2003 19.48 6.52 1237.1, 2004 19.94 7.42 1174.8, 2005 20.53 8.05 1140.5, 2006 20.16 7.18 1542, 2007 21.44 7.91 1167.8, 2008 17.6 5.51 1653.8, 2009 20.63 9.06 1326, 2010 21.31 8.7 1024.8, 2011 21.21 9.96 1847.6, 2012 22.22 9.39 782.5, 2013 20.46 9.29 770.7
    station3       1985 14.43 2.97 951.6, 1986 15.41 3.37 415.6, 1987 15.08 4.34 1110, 1988 16.19 3.33 787.6, 1989 14.77 2.19 796.8, 1990 16.28 4.59 1213.6, 1991 16.72 4.67 907.4, 1992 14.74 4.18 935.6, 1993 15.22 5.06 903.1, 1994 15.46 2.79 907.5, 1995 15.34 4.21 1001.1, 1996 14.46 2.49 1204.5, 1997 14.95 2.95 819, 1998 17.5 5.3 1078.6, 1999 16.73 3.24 901.9, 2000 15.81 2.7 931.4, 2001 16.68 4.09 968.7, 2002 16.48 6.41 762.2, 2003 15.47 4.99 999.6, 2004 15.32 5.31 875.7, 2005 16.16 5.91 593.2, 2006 16.06 6.3 997.2, 2007 15.87 5.71 946, 2008 14.46 4.1 1128.1, 2009 14.26 4.38 1146.1, 2010 15.92 4.79 1037.6, 2011 15.25 5.47 1045.8, 2012 17.47 6.43 659.2, 2013 14.25 4 1092.9, 2014 13.26 2.98 1039.4
    .
    .


Output:



  St_name    max_T_count   min_T_count   precip_count
  station1   1             0             0
  station2   0             2             0
  station3   1             1             1
    .
    .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should at least make an effort to organize your data in a spreadsheet before posting. The first four lines in the code below are just for tidying your data. I am also not sure what you want for `precip_count`, but at least you can work that out based on this solution.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% separate_rows(Met_data, sep = ",") %>%
  mutate(Met_data = trimws(Met_data)) %>%
  separate(Met_data, sep = " ", into = c("year", "max_avg", "min_avg", "total_avg")) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  mutate(max_T_count = as.integer(max_avg == max(max_avg)),
         min_T_count = as.integer(min_avg == min(min_avg)),
         precip_count = as.integer(total_avg == max(total_avg))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(St_name) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(ends_with("count")), sum)
```

- `%>%` is the `magrittr` package pipe operator.
- `separate_rows` separates the entries of the column at commas `Met_data` into new rows.
- `trimws` trims the extra whitespaces around characters. This is necessary in order for `separate` the characters exactly at blanks.
- `separate` separates `Met_data` at blanks and assigns the separated variables with column names.
- `group_by` specifies by which grouping the aggregation is going to be done.
- `mutate` creates new columns.
- `summarise_at` makes summaries on specified columns with specified functions.

These are a handful. I advise you to read the documentations for each of these by typing `?function` where you replace `function` by each of those mentioned above. Or you can use `help` like `help("%>%", package = "magrittr").

Here is the output.

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#   St_name  max_T_count min_T_count precip_count
#   <fct>          <int>       <int>        <int>
# 1 station1           1          17           11
# 2 station2          29           0            5
# 3 station3           0          13           14
```

Here is the data.

```
df <- structure(list(St_name = structure(1:3, .Label = c("station1", 
"station2", "station3"), class = "factor"), Met_data = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 1L), .Label = c("       1985 14.43 2.97 951.6, 1986 15.41 3.37 415.6, 1987 15.08 4.34 1110, 1988 16.19 3.33 787.6, 1989 14.77 2.19 796.8, 1990 16.28 4.59 1213.6, 1991 16.72 4.67 907.4, 1992 14.74 4.18 935.6, 1993 15.22 5.06 903.1, 1994 15.46 2.79 907.5, 1995 15.34 4.21 1001.1, 1996 14.46 2.49 1204.5, 1997 14.95 2.95 819, 1998 17.5 5.3 1078.6, 1999 16.73 3.24 901.9, 2000 15.81 2.7 931.4, 2001 16.68 4.09 968.7, 2002 16.48 6.41 762.2, 2003 15.47 4.99 999.6, 2004 15.32 5.31 875.7, 2005 16.16 5.91 593.2, 2006 16.06 6.3 997.2, 2007 15.87 5.71 946, 2008 14.46 4.1 1128.1, 2009 14.26 4.38 1146.1, 2010 15.92 4.79 1037.6, 2011 15.25 5.47 1045.8, 2012 17.47 6.43 659.2, 2013 14.25 4 1092.9, 2014 13.26 2.98 1039.4", 
"       1985 15.33 4.33 780.1, 1986 12.7 2.18 505.3, 1987 17.76 6.33 793.6, 1988 17.35 4.53 541, 1989 15.65 3.98 793.7, 1990 16.9 5.96 1169.4, 1991 16.42 5.26 790.6, 1992 14.99 5.04 932.6, 1993 13.96 4.75 1420.7, 1994 14.96 3.79 668.8, 1995 15 3.67 952.9, 1996 13.77 2.4 808.5, 1997 14.69 3.26 773.5, 1998 17.22 6.25 1126.4, 1999 16.35 4.32 921.9, 2000 14.55 2.83 893.9, 2001 15.71 4.33 1118.8, 2002 15.61 3.96 1000.4, 2003 14.83 2.84 911.7, 2004 14.9 4 965.1, 2005 16.16 4.7 647.7, 2006 16.18 5.14 800.8, 2007 15.52 4.15 890.3, 2008 14.35 2.91 1271.9, 2009 14.4 3.77 1343.8, 2010 15.32 4.57 1145.4, 2011 15.41 4.54 857.3, 2012 17.39 5.4 745, 2013 15.26 3.51 811.4, 2014 13.8 2.37 986.3", 
"       1985 19.27 7.81 1465.5, 1986 20.37 8.81 1201.3, 1987 20.95 8.72 949.2, 1988 20.03 7.53 1104.6, 1989 19.11 7.42 1050.1, 1990 20.53 8.76 1486.2, 1991 20.21 9.53 1164.4, 1992 19.55 8.51 913.6, 1993 18.7 8.24 1485.1, 1994 19.43 8.42 1171.7, 1995 19.62 7.41 1084.9, 1996 19.01 6.29 1212.4, 1997 18.85 6.76 1243.2, 1998 21 8.27 1261.1, 1999 21.28 7.99 1122.4, 2000 19.99 7.74 1242.7, 2001 20.13 7.59 1305.8, 2002 20.13 7.69 1563, 2003 19.48 6.52 1237.1, 2004 19.94 7.42 1174.8, 2005 20.53 8.05 1140.5, 2006 20.16 7.18 1542, 2007 21.44 7.91 1167.8, 2008 17.6 5.51 1653.8, 2009 20.63 9.06 1326, 2010 21.31 8.7 1024.8, 2011 21.21 9.96 1847.6, 2012 22.22 9.39 782.5, 2013 20.46 9.29 770.7"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("St_name", "Met_data"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: This is really slick. Thanks for showing me `separate_rows`- I had built a custom function to do the same thing. Cheers!

Comment: @hpesoj626. Thanks a bunch. This is what I was looking for. can you please kindly walk me through each step and what it does.? I m new to R language.